# JSON_MODIFY Insert value in the json array by index

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any insert or update value in json array by index.
I have a column with such values:

```
["qwe","123"]
```

and I want to insert new value in the middle:

```
["qwe","asd","123"]
```

or remove one:

```
["123"]
```

how can it be done using `JSON_MODIFY`?

I've only managed to append the last value:

```
select JSON_MODIFY([Column], 'append $', '')
from MyTable
```

or update change the value in the middle to null:

```
select JSON_MODIFY([Column], '$[1]', NULL)
from MyTable
```

and then REPLACE it to nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there isn't a normal way to do it.

I've found only the following way how to do it

```
-- create and fill #TestData
SELECT '["qwe","asd","123"]' json_str
INTO #TestData
UNION ALL
SELECT '["zxc","asd","321"]'
UNION ALL
SELECT '[]'
UNION ALL
SELECT '["qwe","asd","12\"3"]' -- escaped quotes
UNION ALL
SELECT '["qwe","asd","<123>"]' -- special characters

-- delete demo
SELECT
  json_str,
  JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[',STUFF((
      SELECT CONCAT(',"',REPLACE([value],'"','\"'),'"')
      FROM OPENJSON(json_str, '$')
      WHERE [key]<>1 -- exclude element with index 1
      ORDER BY [key]
      FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''),']')) new_json_str
FROM #TestData

-- insert demo
SELECT
  json_str,
  JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[',STUFF((
      SELECT CONCAT(',"',REPLACE([value],'"','\"'),'"')
      FROM
        (
          SELECT 1 RowPriority,[key],[value]
          FROM OPENJSON(json_str, '$')

          UNION ALL

          SELECT
            2 RowPriority,
            0, -- add after key with index 0
            'new value' -- value
          ) q
      ORDER BY [key],RowPriority -- sort values
      FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''),']')) new_json_str
FROM #TestData

DROP TABLE #TestData
```

And one more example to delete values by another condition and to insert several values

```
-- create and fill #TestData
SELECT '["qwe","asd","123"]' json_str
INTO #TestData
UNION ALL
SELECT '["zxc","asd","321"]'
UNION ALL
SELECT '[]' -- empty array
UNION ALL
SELECT '["qwe","asd","12\"3"]' -- escaped quotes
UNION ALL
SELECT '["qwe","asd","<123>"]' -- special characters

-- delete with another condition demo
SELECT
  json_str,
  JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[',STUFF((
      SELECT CONCAT(',"',REPLACE([value],'"','\"'),'"')
      FROM OPENJSON(json_str, '$')
      WHERE [value] NOT IN('qwe','123') -- another delete condition
      ORDER BY [key]
      FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''),']')) new_json_str
FROM #TestData

-- insert several values demo
SELECT
  json_str,
  JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[',STUFF((
      SELECT CONCAT(',"',REPLACE([value],'"','\"'),'"')
      FROM
        (
          SELECT 1 RowPriority,0 NewValOrder,[key],[value]
          FROM OPENJSON(json_str, '$')

          UNION ALL

          SELECT 2 RowPriority,NewValOrder,AfterPosition,[value]
          FROM (VALUES(0,1,'new value 1'),(0,2,'new value 2')) v(AfterPosition,NewValOrder,[value])
          ) q
      ORDER BY [key],RowPriority,NewValOrder -- sort values
      FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''),']')) new_json_str
FROM #TestData

DROP TABLE #TestData
```

Hope this variant will suit you.

A variant with `STRING_AGG` instead `FOR XML PATH('')`

```
-- create and fill #TestData
SELECT '["qwe","asd","123"]' json_str
INTO #TestData
UNION ALL
SELECT '["zxc","asd","321"]'
UNION ALL
SELECT '[]' -- empty array
UNION ALL
SELECT '["qwe","asd","12\"3"]' -- escaped quotes
UNION ALL
SELECT '["qwe","asd","<123>"]' -- special characters

-- delete with another condition demo
SELECT
  json_str,
  JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[',
        (
          SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"',REPLACE([value],'"','\"'),'"'),',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY [key])
          FROM OPENJSON(json_str, '$')
          WHERE [value] NOT IN('qwe','123') -- another delete condition
        ),']')) new_json_str
FROM #TestData

-- insert several values demo
SELECT
  json_str,
  JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[',
        (
          SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"',REPLACE([value],'"','\"'),'"'),',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY [key],RowPriority,NewValOrder)
          FROM
            (
              SELECT 1 RowPriority,0 NewValOrder,[key],[value]
              FROM OPENJSON(json_str, '$')

              UNION ALL

              SELECT 2 RowPriority,NewValOrder,AfterPosition,[value]
              FROM (VALUES(0,1,'new value 1'),(0,2,'new value 2')) v(AfterPosition,NewValOrder,[value])
              ) q
         ),']')) new_json_str
FROM #TestData

DROP TABLE #TestData
```

Maybe the last variant will be better because construction `FOR XML PATH('')` replaces some special characters (for example: `<` - `&lt;`).

Comment: delete fails if item contains escaped quotes:
["1","\"2\""]
I've manged to remove item from the middle using the following code:
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_MODIFY(json_str, '$[1]', ''), '","","','","'),'",""]','"]'), '["","','["' )

Comment: I've added the hack `REPLACE([value],'"','\"')` into all my queries. ) You can check again.

Comment: I've added `ORDER BY [key]` into the old queries and added one more variant with `STRING_AGG` instead `FOR XML PATH('')`. Look at the last query.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to insert new value before the last value, you can append the last value again as `n+1` , then replace the `n` value:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE
(
     [ID] INT
    ,[Column]  NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO @Data ([ID], [Column])
VALUES (1, '["qwe","123"]');


SELECT JSON_MODIFY(JSON_MODIFY([Column], 'append $', JSON_VALUE([Column], '$[1]')), '$[1]', 'asd')
FROM @Data
WHERE [ID] = 1;
```

[image]

Now, if we have many elements, and if we want to insert new element on the second or on the third index, the above will not work as we need to swap all values after the new one.

To do this, we can use the `OPNEJSON` function to split the values, then insert new value with appropriate index and concatenate the values using `FOR XML` or `SRING AGGREGATE` function.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE
(
     [ID] INT
    ,[Column]  NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO @Data ([ID], [Column])
VALUES (2, '["qwe","123", "125" ,"126"]');

SELECT 
'[' + 
STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',' + [value] AS [value]
        FROM
        (
            SELECT JS.[value]
                  ,JS.[key] * 1.0
            FROM @Data DS
            CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([Column]) JS
            WHERE DS.[ID] = 2
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'asd'
                  ,0.1
        ) DS ([value], [key])
        ORDER BY [key]
        FOR XML PATH, TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1
    ,1
    ,''
)
+']';
```

[image]